# Using gRPC proto from referenced project throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I would like to store and build my protos in an external project that can be used in both client and server projects with JsonTranscoding. Unfortunately, gRPC throws an InvalidOperationException:

> 'The stored extension value has a type of 'Google.Api.HttpRule,
> BookingService.RpcApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. This a different from the requested type of
> 'Google.Api.HttpRule, Google.Api.CommonProtos, Version=2.5.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ec5ea7f18953e47'.'"

I have found a similar [problem](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9626) and it seems fixed. I also use the latest NuGet packages but I get this annoying exception.

Everything is fine if I copy all proto files for the relevant projects but it would be better to use the generated classes from an external reusable dll.
Could anyone tell me how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. My case the root cause of the problem was that I set annotations.proto and http.proto to be built. Changed their build action to none solved the exception.

**Edited to add complete solution:**

Do not compile google protos (csproj snippet):

```
<Protobuf Include="google\api\annotations.proto" ProtoCompile="false" GrpcServices="None" />
<Protobuf Include="google\api\http.proto" ProtoCompile="false" GrpcServices="None" />
```

And use *Google.Api.CommonProtos* package.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe useful for someone, I had similar issues I had

```xml
<Protobuf Include="Protos\**\*.proto" GrpcServices="Both" ProtoRoot="Protos\" />
```

and I added `Exclude="Protos\google\**"`

```xml
<Protobuf Include="Protos\**\*.proto" Exclude="Protos\google\**" GrpcServices="Both" ProtoRoot="Protos\" />
```